# Forward port 80 to 8080 for a specific IP on the network

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a specific PC on my network running a web service on port 8080. I also have a different machine which acts as a gateway/router, which I configure using iptables rules.

What I want to do is configure my gateway machine to redirect all traffic to the web server coming from the same LAN to be redirected from port 80 to port 8080.

So, for example, if I type in my browser the web server's IP (which is 192.168.1.75) and press enter it automatically gets redirected to the right port (8080) and I can access the server normally.

I tried this which didn't work:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.75 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.75:8080
```

Comment: Are your desktop and the web server on the same subnet? If so the traffic will not go to your router, it will go direct.

Comment: I think we use the REDIRECT instead of DNAT.
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.75 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`